# How to get start address of the current process and other process's heap from pid?

Tags: ios, linux, macos, process, heap-memory

If the ASLR play a role in IOS and randomize the start address of heap , then how to get the  start address of the current process and other process's heap from pid?

In aslr.c supplied with the paper:"iOS kernel  Exploitation", seems that you try to get the start address of the current process's heap code blew.

```
void* heap = malloc(0);
```

I test the code, find that the return value are not all the same. 
According ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 (i.e. the C99 standard), §7.20.3 states:

*If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: 
either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the ASLR play a role in IOS and randomize the start address of heap,

It does.

> then how to get the start address of the current process and other process's heap from pid?

You can't (at least not easily -- I can't think of any method, short of attaching GDB and examining glibc-internal variable `__curbrk`).

> I test the code, find that the return value are not all the same

Why did you expect them to be the same?

In a *single* executable, with ASLR disabled, `malloc(0)` inside `main` will return the same value. If you enable ASLR, you'll get different values. If you build different executables, you'll get different values.

Comment: Hmmm,seem that it's difficult to get start address of heap. What i want to do is to change the value of other process's variable, but if the variable's memory is allocated on heap, its address would be different every time when the process restarts :(. So I want to check out that whether the variable's relative address is fixed. If the offset is fixed,through get the start address of heap, then i could get the variable's address.